# What are the diff between the lookup and queryset functions of django's SimpleListFilter class

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am reading this for simple list filter in django amdin

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter

He has defined two functions `lookups` and `queryset`

i want to know what is the diff and when to use lookup and when to use queryset. what dores lookup means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lookups` returns the items in the list that will appear on the right (in the example the list will contain the values 'in the 80's' and 'in the 90's').

`queryset` defines which objects should be shown on the left when a specific lookup is selected.

Each lookup item is made of two values; the value actually shown on the screen and another value which will be used by the queryset method to filter the main object list.

If the user selects 'in the 80's' then the queryset method will take the value '80s' (from `self.value()`) and create a filter that returns people who's birthdays are in the 80's. (that's the first `if` statement in the queryset method). The main object list in the admin page is then populated by the objects from this filter.

Comment: thanks buddy , dou know what is the `change list page` which django often refers in the docs

Comment: It's the page we're talking about here (the object list is the list of objects that you can change - hence 'change list'). The first image you see when you follow the link you included above - that's a 'change list page'.